# Moodle errror Error: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, syntax-error, web-hosting, moodle

i have hosted a moodle server on an online server hoster. now when i went to my moodle page, the following error occurred: Error: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)
also i set to see more information and the following came up:Fehler: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)
Debug info:
Error code: generalexceptionmessage
Stack trace:
line 3899 of /lib/adminlib.php: ParseError thrown
line 276 of /lib/classes/plugin_manager.php: call to core_plugin_manager->load_enabled_plugins()
line 5273 of /lib/navigationlib.php: call to core_plugin_manager->get_enabled_plugins()
line 4962 of /lib/navigationlib.php: call to settings_navigation->generate_user_settings()
line 4358 of /lib/navigationlib.php: call to settings_navigation->load_user_settings()
line 833 of /lib/pagelib.php: call to settings_navigation->initialise()
line 962 of /lib/pagelib.php: call to moodle_page->magic_get_settingsnav()
line 598 of /lib/classes/navigation/views/secondary.php: call to moodle_page->__get()
line 72 of /theme/boost/layout/drawers.php: call to core\navigation\views\secondary->get_overflow_menu_data()
line 1477 of /lib/outputrenderers.php: call to include()
line 1403 of /lib/outputrenderers.php: call to core_renderer->render_page_layout()
line 179 of /my/index.php: call to core_renderer->header()

I tried to host a new server but the same error occurs

Comment: You are almost certainly using the wrong PHP version with your Moodle code. You haven't stared the Moodle version you are trying to run (presumably the latest, Moodle 4.2) or the PHP version you are running on your server (presumably not PHP 8.0, which is the minimum for Moodle 4.2)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have Moodle version 4.2 and PHP version 7.4.8, not version 8.0.  But I do not know how to change the php version at an infinityfree.com server

Comment: It's explained here : https://forum.infinityfree.net/t/how-to-change-php-version/68556
While you're at it, check your database version (it's available here : https://moodledev.io/general/releases/4.2 )